# How to count unique dimensions in AWS CloudWatch metrics?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

Let's say my application publishes AWS CloudWatch metrics with a single dimension. The value of that dimension can be any string. Then, in any given time interval, I'll have something like this:

```
(myDimension: "foo", value: 12)
(myDimension: "bar", value: 5)
(myDimension: "foo", value: 99)
(myDimension: "quux", value: 42)
```

Now I want to create an alarm based on a metric derived from this. I want to ignore the values and only count the *unique* occurrences of each dimension. In this case, the value would be 3 -- 1 for "foo" (even though it appeared twice), 1 for "bar" and 1 for "quux".

How can I do that? I've looked at the [Metric Math](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html) documentation, but I didn't find any function that could help me. The one that seems to get close is `IF`, but I'm not sure if I can use it to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using CloudWatch Insights
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html

Create a query similar to this:

```
parse @message '*(myDimension: "*"*' as f1, myDimensionKey, f2
| filter @message like '(myDimension:'
| stats count(*) by myDimensionKey
```

And add the result to a dashboard. This would display a table with the distinct keys and the number of occurrences

Comment: Can I add an alarm on this?

Comment: Unfortunately there is not a direct integration between the queries and alarms. "You can write a bit of glue code to run queries, use the results to publish Custom Metrics. Then you can visualize them, set alarms, and so forth, all with the goal of simplifying and accelerating your troubleshooting." So basically you can use the AWS API in a lambda function the run the queries and then set alarms bases on custom metrics. https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/aws/new-amazon-cloudwatch-logs-insights-fast-interactive-log-analytics/